# MVC - Receive Form with Viewbag Variable from database and passing to the view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a html form into my database.

In this form i have a value which contains a Viewbag,

for example value="@Viewbag.MyVariable"

In my view when i try to receive my form all works fine,

but my problem is that the Viewbag value are not converting
to the value which comes from my controller.

any ideia how to resolve this ?

my code:

View:

```
   @Html.Raw(p.Form)
```

My form in my database looks like:

```
<form action="/MyController/MyAction" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="num" value="@ViewBag.num" /> 
  ....
  ....
  ....
</form>
```

What i have try to do was with:

```
Stringbuilder a=new Stringbuilder;
@Html.Raw(a.To.String())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should technically work, if you are using MVC you could try

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(p.Form);
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.. but still not working.. the value are not converted... any ideia?

Comment: i have found a solution and now is solved.. but thanks for the tip

Comment: @user2232273 It's worth posting your solution incase others have a similar problem.

Comment: i know it i always post my solution..because in my opinion if all share his solution and discussion about the issue, we all can learn and become better.. give me 5 min

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution and now i solved it.**

**what i have done:**

in my form the only part which are different from the others
forms are the dropdownlists.

i only put the part from `<select>` to `</select>` in my 
database. (only the dynamically part of my form)

in my view i have write my form and only insert the variable
which comes from my controller to insert the data from my 
database on the right part in my form.

here is the code:

```
<form action="/MyController/MyAction" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="num" value="@ViewBag.num" /> 

            @MvcHtmlString.Create(p.Form);           

    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

So i have never more the problem with the variables to be
converted, because the variables are still the same